# Extract multiple types of pattern from string

Tags: r

I am extracting multiple types of pattern from a string. For example,

"Listed 03/25/2013 for 25000 and sold for $10,250 on 4/5/2010"

I would like to extract dates "03/25/2013" "4/5/2010" to vector 'dates', and "25000" "$10,250" to vector amounts.

```
text <- "Listed 03/25/2013 for 25000 and sold for $10,250 on 4/5/2010"
  # extract dates
dates <- str_extract_all(text,"\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4}")[[1]]
  # extract amounts
text2 <- as.character(gsub("\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4}", " ", text))
amountsdollar <- as.character(str_extract_all(text2,"\\$\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?"))
text3 <- as.character(gsub("\\$\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?", " ", text2))
amountsnum <- as.character(str_extract_all(text3,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?"))
amounts <- as.vector(c(amountsdollar, amountsnum))
list(dates, amounts)
```

But the order is not kept. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: [I’ve written a small function for this](https://gist.github.com/klmr/5555335) – it does more or less the same as the stringr function but it does keep the order.

Comment: @KonradRudolph what's wrong with `regmatches`?

Comment: @Matthew The fact that I didn’t know it. Sigh. That’ll teach me to read the documentation properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

base R handles this fine

```
x <- "Listed 03/25/2013 for 25000 and sold for $10,250, on 4/5/2010"
date.pat <- '\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2,4}'
amount.pat <- '(?<=^| )[$,0-9]+[0-9](?=,|\\.|$| )'

dates <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(date.pat, x))
amounts <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(amount.pat, x, perl=TRUE))
```

Comment: +1: I think the world does need more worked examples of the `regmatches(x, gregexpr(.))` paradigm.

Comment: It takes comma when there is one after the number, say $100,000, how can i extract $100,000 only? Thanks

Comment: You are an expert! Thanks a lot!